# React Native Flatlist warnings: VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update & Excessive number of pending callbacks

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I have a local array of emoji objects (4000+) that i render in a modal.

Through research, i found that using Flatlist would be best for performance.
It works in the app, though a bit laggy, but i get two warnings in the terminal:

```
Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. 
Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from 
native code

&

VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update 
- make sure your renderItem function renders components that 
follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. 
{"contentLength": 4239.66650390625, "dt": 607, "prevDt": 514}
```

Here is my code:

```js
export const EmojiPicker = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [selectedEmoji, setSelectedEmoji] = useState(() => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * emojis.length);
    return emojis[random];
  });

  const renderEmoji = (emoji) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          setSelectedEmoji(emoji);
          setShowModal(!showModal);
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.emoji} size={30}>
          {emoji.char}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
      >
        <Text size={30}>{selectedEmoji.char}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <SwipeableModal
        isVisible={showModal}
        onClose={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
      >
          <FlatList
            data={emojis}
            renderItem={({ item }) => renderEmoji(item)}
            horizontal={false}
            numColumns={6}
            key={6}
            initialNumToRender={5}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.codes}
          />
      </SwipeableModal>
    </>
  );
};
```

How can i improve performance and remove the warnings?

**UPDATE**:

I got rid of the first warning (Excessive number of pending callbacks) by exchaning all the TouchableOpacity elements with Pressable from react-native. It is a known issue:
[Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27483)

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Comment: Tangential, but IMO a scrollable list with 4k entries is too much scrolling.

Comment: There is a search bar hehe

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating a dedicated pure component for your emoji. A pure component does not re-render when its props does not change. This is particularly useful in a list when the component depends on its position in the list and not any external value.
See this guide if you want more information about them: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/PureComponent#migrating-from-a-purecomponent-class-component-to-a-function

```js
import { memo } from 'react';

const Emoji = memo(({ emoji }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setSelectedEmoji(emoji);
        setShowModal(!showModal);
      }}
    >
      <Text style={styles.emoji} size={30}>
        {emoji.char}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
});

// ...

<FlatList
  data={emojis}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Emoji emoji={item} />}
  // ...
/>
```

Be careful: Because your inner components won't get re-rendered on every change of parent state (`showModal`), the `onPress` callback will keeps its original definition. It may or may not be an issue in your case, but I would recommend you to use the updater callback of the "setState" function:

```ts
onPress={() => {
  setSelectedEmoji(emoji);
  setShowModal(wasShowingModal => !wasShowingModal);
}}
// The callback given to setShowModal will be invoked with
// the previous state at the time of the call, and not the
// value at the time the onPress callback is defined.
```